# "Paused in debugger" after clicking "resume script execution"

Tags: electron, google-chrome-devtools

[image]

I set breakpoint in the devtool but it still `pasued in debugger` after I clicked `resume script execution`

This case I must restart the dev server.

---

I can reproduce the problem. If you're interested I push the code to github. address : https://github.com/mqliutie/electron-debugger.